# EF4: Save object children

Tags: entity-framework-4, wcf-data-services

in database I have these tables: Product, Request and RequestProducts.
RequestProducts is a table to link many Product to one Request.

Here is my code:

```js
        Product newProduct = new Product
                                 {
                                     Unity_ID = 3,
                                     Quantity = 2,
                                     Name = "toto",
                                     AlreadyCurrency = true
                                 };

        Request newRequest = new Request
                                 {
                                     User_ID = 1,
                                     CaseNumber = 1,
                                     Draft = false
                                 };

        newRequest.Products.Add(newProduct);

        _db.AddToProducts(newProduct);
        _db.AddToRequests(newRequest);
        _db.SaveChanges();
```

After execute that, in my database I get 1 product and 1 request. It's ok, but the link create with line `newRequest.Products.Add(newProduct);` is not created the table RequestProducts and yet EF4 understand the link by propose me the `Products` list in the Request object.

Is it possible to create this link only with this code?

Thank you!

Comment: as per your comments on my answer, I've updated it.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need an extra table for a one-to-many relationship.  You'd only need that extra table for many-to-many relationships.

So, without knowing more specifics about what you're doing and why, I'd say it's working properly.

Ideally, your Request object would look something like:

```
public class Request
{
    public int RequestId {get; set;}
    //Other defining params here

    public ICollection<Product> Products {get; set;}
}
```

Then your Product object would look like:

```
public class Product
{
    public int ProductId {get; set;}
    //other defining params
    public int RequestId {get; set;} //your FK

    public virtual Request Request {get; set;} //If you ever need the Product to be aware of the Request to which it is attached.
}
```

Comment: Oh it's true, I don't need this extra table!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you use generated entities of EDMX, you should have a single `RequestId` FK column in your `Product` table.

Then after you generate the EDMX from DB, there will not be additional tables, so you should then be able to do it this way:

```
Request newRequest = new Request
                         {
                             User_ID = 1,
                             CaseNumber = 1,
                             Draft = false
                         };

Product newProduct = new Product
                         {
                             Unity_ID = 3,
                             Quantity = 2,
                             Name = "toto",
                             AlreadyCurrency = true,
                             Request = newRequest
                         };


//Redundant
//newRequest.Products.Add(newProduct);

_db.AddToProducts(newProduct);

//Redundant
_db.AddToRequests(newRequest);

_db.SaveChanges();

//Never forget - or wrap in a using statement
_db.Dispose()
```

**Update**

1. The case above is one2many (one request has many products)
2. becuase as soon as I set the `Request` (which is now a property of the `Product`) to `newRequest`, then when I add it to the context (or if it's already added), all the related entities of the whole graph will automatically be added too.
3. Read [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb738763.aspx) carefully.

Comment: @Shimmy: When I do that I get exception in my FK: 
`ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Product]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_Product_Request] FOREIGN KEY([RequestID])
REFERENCES [dbo].[Request] ([ID])` and in my context the method `Dispose()` doesn't exist!

Comment: When you do what? When you try to change your database? BTW, as a good advice, I'd suggest you to use [diagrams](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188251.aspx), this will give you a visual model of your database - tables and relationships. For your convenience it's available in Visual Studio as well

Comment: @Shimmy: I have change my database and code. Now I can use your code, but I get the exception on your `SaveChanges()` and yes I use diagram but not in Visual Studio, I use it in SQL Server

Comment: Did you regenerate the model from database? Go to your EDMX designer, right click the surface and select "Generate Model from Database". If your model reflects your database and you haven't made any changes when you created the model, then you can delete your tables, and they will be regenerated and overriden anew. BTW, According to your first comment, the exception looks very weird. it seems that your database has not yet been modified. make sure you saved your diagram, then regenerate model from database, the code should then work.

Comment: Regarding to the `Dispose`, it's a method of the `ObjectContext`, read my updated answer (no. 3).

Comment: @Shimmy: I have recreated the link in the SQL diagram between Product and Request, then I have deleted all the table in the EDMX diagram and updated the model from database. Recompiled and updated service reference. And no... always the same error. The exact exception is **The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "FK_Product_Request". The conflict occurred in database "SuiP", table "dbo.Request", column 'ID'.**. My _db object isn't a `ObjectContext` it's a `DataServiceContext` because I'm using WCF Data Contract

Comment: Column 'ID' is an Identity column

Comment: I am gonna leave now, will be back tomorrow. but with WCF it's a slightly different story where you do have to mess with the IDs instead the navigation properties. is it WCF or WCF-RIA?